# How to do a Pagereload, when a Ruby Rake Task is finished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

i'am working on a Message System, there is a Rake Task run every 2 Min to check, if there are new incoming Messages. It would be nice to do a Pagerefresh, after this Process, so that the User is up to date.

What is the best way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: you might want to look at using actioncable for something like this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Comment: Thank you, Actioncable could be very good for my problem. 
But anyway i'm still wondering how to do a Pagerefresh at the end of an Rake Task.